# Adding value and sorting them in python class

Tags: python

I would like to form a list by adding numbers one by one. When numbers is added, the list will be sorted by ascending. For this reason, I wrote codes as below but when I execute these codes, the order of numbers in the list become as I added. What is wrong with these codes?

```
class SortList:
    theList = []
    theempty = []

    def sorttheList(self,number):
        self.theempty.append(number)
        for i in range(len(self.theempty)):
            mini = min(self.theempty)
            self.theList.append(mini)
            self.theempty.remove(mini)
    return self.theList

    def printList(self):
        return print(self.theList)

lst = SortList()
lst.sorttheList(2)
lst.sorttheList(4)
lst.sorttheList(9)
lst.sorttheList(15)
lst.sorttheList(0)

lst.printList()
```

Comment: What is the need of `i` in the `for i in range(len(self.theempty)):` ?

Comment: I realized that the for loop is unnecessary. I thought I was able to get the minimum value of list with a for loop. By the way, I am beginner in programming. :)

Answer (score 1):

`theempty` only ever has the last value passed to `sorttheList`, so that is always appended to the end of `theList`.

You might be better off using Python's built-in sorting methods.

Comment: I should write the sort and add function without using Python's built-in method.